# Upload to VPP Business Store greyed out

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, apple-vpp

i am trying to upload a custom B2B app through iTunes Connect, but the "available on the vpp business store" option is greyed out.

[image]

Is there anything else i have to do in order to upload my custom B2B application?

Comment: I have the same issue, yet it worked fine for other apps before they changed the UI. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I have not found a solution yet. I will post the solution here when i work it out.

Comment: If your app is in the rejected state then also not possible to select B2B options, Just contact to apple support.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Found it!** After contacting Apple Developers Support, i got the answer and it worked!

They answered me:

> Please be advised that in order to submit a Business to Business app
>   you will need to agree to a paid apps conrtact in iTunes Connect
>   "Agreements Tax, and Banking".  A paid apps contract is required even
>   if you intend to price the app at no charge in the business to
>   business store.

Hope this helps other people too...

Comment: I have paid apps contract, I have running paid apps in the AppStore, but VPP-only option is still disabled. Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

I have to accept the upgrade license agree from itunesconnect for use then. Then i can modify all.